# VSCode doesn't do intellisense for classes in different root folder

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with Javascript/Meteor, and this is the basics of my folder structure.

```
definition_doesnt_work.js
-client
-models
  definition_doesnt_work.js
-server
  emails
     emailfile.js
     definition_works.js
  test
     definition_works.js
```

I have some code in `emailfile.js` that makes use of a javascript `class`.  If I define the class in either of the `definition_works.js` files, VSCode intellisense recognizes the class and provides intellisense.  However, if I put the class definition in the either of the `definition_doesnt_work.js` files, the definition doesn't work.  So it seems like in order for vscode to recognize a class definition, it has to be in the same root folder as another item.  Is there a way I can make it read from definitions in other folders.  Here is my jsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the jsconfig? At the root of the project?

Comment: Ah, you found it!  I found I had one in the server directory in addition to the root directory!! Removing the one in the server directory fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just posting comment as the answer*

In this case, it seems the files were part of two different `jsconfig.json` projects which is why the definition was not being picked up.

You can easily check which `jsconfig` a file belongs to by running the `JavaScript: Go to Project Configuration` command in VS Code